# ListViewBuiler inside Row flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, row

i am trying to add a listview inside a row , but i got this Error

[image]

I have in the row Two widgets the first one with a column , the second widget is the listview builder that return another widget .

I am trying to make the row look like below picture

[image]

this is my code

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/meee.jpg"))),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.blue, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                            child: Text(
                              "+",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "Your Story",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 3,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return __buildStory();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing this line

```
ListView.builder(
```

with this line

```
ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true,
```

If it does not work, consider wrapping your `ListView.builder` widget in a `Flexible` widget

```
Flexible(child:
```

Comment: Can you please see my comment below

Comment: Did you try using "Flexible"?

Answer (score 0):

Since `ListView` need all the remaining space in `Row`, wrap the `ListView.builder` with a `Expanded`. Also use `shrinkWrap:true` in `ListView`.

Add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to `Column`.

```dart
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/meee.jpg"))),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.blue, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                            child: Text(
                              "+",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "Your Story",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 3,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return __buildStory();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: with Expanded i got error constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true , so i remplaced Expanded with SizedBox , and added a height to  the sSizedBox and its working now , but is there any way to make the SizedBox to take the height of the  child ? because without height i got again this error "  constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true "

Comment: Try the updated solution.

Comment: still getting this error " 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true" , i need to add height

Comment: Debug and identify the widget causing the error

Answer (score 0):

this should solve your problem

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
               children: List.generate(3,
                (index) => widget)),
             )
```